# React app for cordova shows white screen for android

Tags: android, cordova, reactjs

I tried to convert a react application into a mobile app, i got success with iOS, but now, when I'm trying with android, it shows the white screen of death, and the chrome remote inspector doesn't show any significant reason, this is the chrome log

[image]

this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>MMJ Recs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"/>
    <script>
        window.prompt = function(){

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/build.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_AzADtnJ7sM7pQJu32JOmHB3M');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


//ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
function startApp(){
    Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler) {
        React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('app'));
    });
}

function startAppCordova(){
    Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {
        React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('app'));
    });
}


window.onload = function(){
    var url = document.URL;
    var isSmart = (url.indexOf("http://") === -1 && url.indexOf("https://") === -1);
    if( isSmart ){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', startAppCordova, false);
    }
    else{
        startApp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it could be a problem with the JavaScript engine, for older phones which have older JS engines you can use a Polyfill downloaded from https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/, which I used it to sort out this error which I saw when running `adb logcat` with my phone connected and opened the app :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign
```

Run `adb logcat` to see what the error is in your case, you probably won't see it from the Chrome console

Comment: Well, I resolved it already, I used this repo for guidance https://github.com/swennemans/react-cordova-reflux, and I didn't noticed that the config.xml has many plugins from different platforms, that was causing conflict with android, it really took me several ours to figure out, any way, thanks for your  time